# Delete from PC table the computers having minimal hdd size or minimal ram size

Tags: sql, sql-delete

PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)

I am writing the query

```
delete from PC  
where exists
(select model , min(hd), min(ram) from PC
group by model)
```

but not getting correct result

Expected result is

```
 code   model   speed   ram hd  cd  price
    2   1121    750 128 14.0    40x 850.0000
    4   1121    600 128 14.0    40x 850.0000
    5   1121    600 128 8.0 40x 850.0000
    6   1233    750 128 20.0    50x 950.0000
    8   1232    450 64  8.0 24x 350.0000
    11  1233    900 128 40.0    40x 980.0000
```

Can someone correct me in my query ?

Comment: Are you trying to delete only the record with the minimum HD and RAM?

Comment: Please can you clarify your question a bit more?  Are you trying to delete ALL records with the minimum RAM OR minimum HD i.e. 5 & 8?  Or are you trying to delete the record with the minimum RAM AND the minimum HD  i.e. 8?

As @JimJimson has pointed out there's a distinction between deleting one specific row, or any row which matches specific criteria.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EXISTS will just delete anything from the table where the EXISTS condition is true. You can find out more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You need to delete only the records you're after, which points to a window function. You can find out more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

If you're just trying to delete the record with the lowest hd and ram then the below should help you on your way. Beware the below will order first by hd and then by ram. So the record with the smallest hd will always be deleted first.

```
BEGIN TRAN;
DELETE p FROM PC p
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Code,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY model ORDER BY hd DESC, ram DESC) [RNum]
) m ON m.Code = p.Code AND m.RNum = 1;
--COMMIT TRAN;
--ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

Comment: The question says "minimal HD size OR minimal ram size".  This deletes records with the maximum ram on the maximum HDD.  I fail to see how this even begins to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want a correlation clause.  Otherwise, you are deleting either all rows (if the subquery returns any rows) or no rows (if the subquery returns no rows).

What is confusing you is the `group by`.  You want a correlation clause instead.  I would write this as two different comparisons:

```
delete from PC  
where hd = (select min(hd)
            from PC pc2
            where pc2.model = pc.model
           ) or
      ram = (select min(ram) 
             from PC pc2
             where pc2.model = pc.model
            );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon.